# Ng-repeat a function with json Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new in Angular. I'm trying to do an application. Before I did

[this](http://plnkr.co/edit/hISwTllbaa60Vlpld7Nk?p=preview) (watch the second Fork, in the middle, not the last one)

that there are two selection: the second one is empty and auto complete with a subarray of the option chosen in the first select. This works.

Now, this is for a table that I'm doing. In fact the rows contain the two selection above. I will add also a button for ADD new line, so with new selection. I've tried to iterate, but of course it doesn't work.... In this update [THIS](http://plnkr.co/edit/8bOxIW2JJIhRUGCuVMzx?p=preview) you can see that in the script.js i've added new code (i made comments). I've created one array to include all the info, one function to add new line and one function to delete line. But of course it doesn't work....... what I am doing wrong?

In particular this is the new lines of js' code:

```
 $scope.allInfo = [
  {
     "Product ID" : $scope.selectedProduct.id,
     "Product Nome" : $scope.selectedProduct.nome,
     "Product Codice": $scope.selectedProduct.codice,
     "Lot ID" : $scope.selectedLot.id,
     "Lot Value" : $scope.selectedLot.value
  }   
 ];

$scope.foods = [
 {
  "select1": "",
  "select2": ""
 }
]


$scope.newLine = function () {
  var itemToAdd = { "select1": "", "select2": ""};
 $scope.allInfo.push(itemToAdd);
}

$scope.removeLine = function (itemIndex) {
  $scope.foods.splice(itemIndex, 1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, In the newLine method, you need to read the `$scope.selectedProduct` and $`scope.selectedLot` and use that to create a new item which you will be pushing to `$scope.allInfo` array.

```
 $scope.newLine = function () {

    var itemToAdd = { "select1": $scope.selectedProduct.descrizione,
                      "select2": $scope.selectedLot.value};
    $scope.allInfo.push(itemToAdd);
}
```

And now in your UI, you can use ng-repeat to display the items in `$scope.allInfo`

```
<h1>INFO ABOUT SELECTION</h1>

<div ng-repeat="item in allInfo">
  {{item.select1}} - {{item.select2}}
</div>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CccWtcpJlGKPRhlmuDci?p=preview) is a working sample.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it is not what i'm a looking for! I don't mean to add the selected line... i mean to repeat the whole line, repeat the <select>. At the beginning i have: <select></select> <select></select> <button></button> <button></button>. When i press add line, i would to duplicate <select></select> <select></select> <button> etc. Make completely a new line, with new field!